# Is there any coding involved when making a game with something like blender or UDK?

Tags: blender

With these programs, it seems like every aspect of the game is done through the GUI.  Is there any coding when making games through these programs?  Like would you code in collision detection, or would that be done through the GUI?

Comment: animation or the gui is updated depending on the game logic so in cases like collision detection, it's done in the game logic instead of the drawing/graphics part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Unreal engine but Unity3D and SIO2 but the situation should be similar. Basically a lot of programming is taken from you and can be done through setting properties like in a Blender material. But at the end you have to do at least a little bit of coding.

The process of collision detection for example involves attaching a collider to your player character and another one to your obstacle. Then you have to attach a small script to your player like this.

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider collider) {
    if (collider.material.name.Equals ("ObstaclePhysicMaterial")) {
        player.PlayAnimation ("Die");
        // your code snippet to game over or whatever
    }
}
```

Not too abstract but it has to be done and of course your game over logic will include some more code to reset all objects to their initial position. So at the end you cannot avoid coding but when I started learning Blender I made the experience that more complex Blender scenes have indeed similarities to programming. You have to plan your scene and find the most efficient structure to avoid unnecessary work i.e. thinking in terms of logic is slightly analogue.

So if you plan a game with heavy graphics and not too sophisticated logic I like to encourage you to give scripting a try. Start with studying sample projects.

Answer (score 0):

With development kits you usually get. The most important part the engine. Sometimes materials and land scape tools. All you do really is the scripting part. Events, environmental variables, usually in LUA or python. Not the actual engine and physics.... the hard part.